# Error while submitting form using AJAX and php

Tags: ajax, templates, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

Hii i am trying to save data of form to user meta data table by using javascript, AJAX and php. Here is my code

HTML Form:

```
    <form id="savem" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="profile_name" id="profile_name"/>

    <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1"/>

    <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"/>

    <input type="submit" value="save"/>

    </form>
```

Enqueued the script in functions.php

```
    function save_measurment() {

$theme_url  = get_template_directory_uri();     // Used to keep our Template Directory URL
$ajax_url   = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );        // Localized AJAX URL

// Register Our Script for Localization
wp_register_script(
    'measurment',                             // Our Custom Handle
    "{$theme_url}/assets/js/measurment.js",  // Script URL, this script is located for me in `theme-name/scripts/um-modifications.js`
    array( 'jquery' ),                              // Dependant Array
    '1.0',                                          // Script Version ( Arbitrary )
    true                                            // Enqueue in Footer
);

// Localize Our Script so we can use `ajax_url`
wp_localize_script(
    'measurment',
    'ajax_url',
    $ajax_url
);

// Finally enqueue our script
wp_enqueue_script( 'measurment' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'save_measurment' );
```

Javascript function to process meta values:

```
    jQuery( 'document' ).ready( function( $ ) {

// Form submission listener
$( '#savem' ).submit( function() {
    var measrumentData = {};
    // Grab our post meta value
     measrumentData.profile_name = $( '#savem #profile_name' ).val();
     measrumentData.value1 = $(' #savem #value1').val();
    measrumentData.value2 = $(' #savem #value2').val();

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(measrumentData);

    // Do very simple value validation

        $.ajax( {
            url : ajax_url,                 // Use our localized variable that holds the AJAX URL
            type: 'POST',                   // Declare our ajax submission method ( GET or POST )
            data:  {data: jsonString},
        } )
        .success( function( results ) {
            console.log( 'User Meta Updated!' );
        } )
        .fail( function( data ) {
            console.log( data.responseText );
            console.log( 'Request failed: ' + data.statusText );
        } );


    return false;   // Stop our form from submitting
} );
  } );
```

and finally the ajax callback function

```
    function measurment_callback() {

// Ensure we have the data we need to continue
if( ! isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

    // If we don't - return custom error message and exit
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 Empty POST Values' );
    echo 'Could Not Verify POST Values.';
    exit;
}

$user_id = get_current_user_id();            // Get our current user ID
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
   add_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $value ); 
}

exit;
   }
```

Now whats happening is while submitting the form the console is showing meta values updated but phpmyadmin is giving error message "null is not an object (evaluating 'field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)')".
I have no idea whats wrong so any help will be appreciable

Comment: Is the HTML form on the front end?

Comment: yes it is front ent Html form

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are trying to set object properties that are undefined.

Your javascript should look like this

```
var measrumentData = {
    profile_name:null,
    value_one:null,
    value_two:null

};
// Grab our post meta value
measrumentData.profile_name = $( '#savem #profile_name' ).val();
measrumentData.value_one = $(' #savem #value1').val();
measrumentData.value_two = $(' #savem #value2').val();
```

or

```
var measrumentData = {};
// Grab our post meta value
 measrumentData['profile_name'] = $( '#savem #profile_name' ).val();
 measrumentData['value1'] = $(' #savem #value1').val();
measrumentData['value2'] = $(' #savem #value2').val();
```

Comment: tried this but with no help. its still giving the same error report :(